# Firefox & AJAX oddity: DOM replacements not working again after just working

Tags: ajax, firefox, function-call

these are the two functions (externally loaded):

```
function replaceText(element, text) {
    if (element != null) {
        clearText(element);
        var newNode = document.createTextNode(text);
        element.appendChild(newNode);
    }
}

function replaceImage(element, maker, imageState) {
    replaceText(element, "replacing image " + maker + " with " + imageState + " version");
    var imagePath = "_img/coffeeMaker_";
    if (maker != null)
    {
        document.getElementById("coffeeMakerImg"+ maker).src = imagePath + imageState + ".png";
    }
}
```

now here's the part that calls these functions. *notice that the `replaceText()` is called from within `replaceImage()`

```
replaceText(cmStatus_01, "BREWING " + name + "'s " + size + " " + beverage);
replaceImage("feedback", "01", "full");
document.forms[0].reset();
```

okay.  now here's the kicker: the FIRST `replaceText()` works fine in ALL browsers.  the `replaceImage()` fails ONLY in Firefox which CONTAINS A CALL TO `replaceText()` that only JUST worked as advertised!!  i could see how i might have screwed up the image replacement (even though i copy/pasted it from another working project that DOES replace the image in FF...so weird...), but i do NOT see how the `replaceText()` can fail: it just worked!

so: whaaaaat!?  i'm thinking its some kind of scope issue, but i'm stumped as to why.

totally stumped.  forehead really sore...

thank for your time and help.  i'm praying this isn't something really retarded...

WR!

PS:  i'm also confused why, if i remove the quotes from the element name in the `replaceImage()` call, it breaks; but it works in the `replaceText()` call without brackets just fine...

Comment: quick addendum:  i was running the Error Console in Firefox and it shows 'feedback is not defined'.  ??  do not know what to do with that information, but someone might...

Comment: Can you recreate the problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can attempt to debug this?

Comment: ...never used jsFiddle before!  i can try.

Comment: ...and no.  sorry.  i don't have the time to figure out what jsFiddle does right now.  i'll zip the package and make it available it you like.

Comment: Well, that's better than nothing, so go for it.

Comment: okay.  i figured it out.  but because my rep is low, i can't post solution for another six hours.  stay tuned... in essence, i was passing div names in one and non-div names in another.

Answer (score 0):

okay.  i figured it out.  the problem was actually what i was passing into the functions:

`cmStatus_01` was NOT the actual ID of the div.  it was evaluated earlier like so:

```
var cmStatus_01 = document.getElementById('divName');
```

but i WAS passing the `divName` into the `replaceImage()` function and it was expecting the evaluted version of it, like `cmStatus_01`.  so it broke.

so when i actually retooled the function so i was ONLY passing `divName`, it obviously worked.  this is the retool:

```
function replaceNodeText(id, newText)
{
    var node = document.getElementById(id);
    while (node.firstChild)
    {
        node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
    }
    node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newText));
}
```

project deadline too tight!  it's making my brain fail.  :P

also: apologies for not posting where the variables came from.  that would have helped enormously, i'm sure and i don't know why i didn't think to post them as well.

thank you for your patience and your time.

WR!